# Unable get 600,000 deletion stubs ro purge from database

Tags: lotus-domino

Update: I have issued a: show database mycleandb.nsf and I can see there are still 835,000 deletion stubs. I can't seem to remove them.

Summary:
We have a large database that we are now ready to start trimming down to a more manageable size.
I deleted the documents, but I am left with a database it appears I can't copy or replicate, receiving error: Unable to extend an ID table - insufficient memory.

Detail:
Current live database has roughly 1,400,000 docs in it, we can immediately reduce it to 650,000.  With some further design\ architectural work we can reduce this to 300,000.  This web application is clustered on 5 servers, 1 being the application "hub", with 3 HTTP\SSO servers behind a reverse proxy and the 5th server is the access point for external services.  The HUB initiates a PUSH\PULL replication (with no document restrictions) every 30mins, logs show no replication errors.  Transaction logging is set for Run Time performance on servers, back up is performed on another back server not in cluster.  We run daily archiving that archives roughly 1,500 docs a day.

So far, nearly 2 years on, application has run fine...apart from a few nightmares here and there :-).  But, we are finally at point we can trim the databases down.

Prior to any work I OS backed up the live DB, and copied it to a test server. On a test server I did a: CL copy mylivedb.nsf mycleandb.nsf
In mycleandb.nsf I then deleted docs to reduce the DB to 650,000 documents.

All I'm after is a new copy, not a replica, see replica issue below, so I issued another command...to give me a new copy without deletion stubs, it's my understanding that a COPY does not copy del' stubs.:
CL copy mycleandb.nsf mycleandbNEW.nsf
...this also ensures that if any rogue replica is out on the network, we don't get allt he docs back in (not all our servers are 8.5.3, so we can't use the Database Property to set a cut off date for deletion stubs)

But I got a: Unable to extend an ID table - insufficient memory.
Tried this:
CL copy mycleandb.nsf mycleandbNEW.nsf REPLICA
...same thing.

Tried steps found here to my mycleandb.nsf:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220384
...same thing.

Changed purge interval to 0 days as described here, also set purge date into future:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21095683
...same thing.

Then ran a:
load compact mycleandb.nsf -B
...same thing.

I have seen this thread here, which is a similar situation, except, we don't have any issues with clustering\ replication...yet!
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/74d3e0f5467f843885257aaf0081abe5?OpenDocument

So, I have a DB I have deleted docs from, I can open it, it appears to function, but I can't copy\ replicate it.

Replication\ Cluster Issue:
I have seen this error before: Unable to extend an ID table - insufficient memory...and what I have done, is drop one of our primary servers, OS copy the DB to server with issue, restart.

I have always created new replicas using Admin Client\ Dom console, but in this case, whenever I do it floods the database with documents, but purge intervals are correct on all servers. The new replicas have been created from the HUB server, which initiates PUSH\PULL replication with all the cluster mates every 30mins, so if this was a deletion stub issue, it would manifest itself all the time?

I will NotesPeek it tomorrow to see if any deletion stubs are still there, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any comments or suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: when you write "same thing." do you mean you also get the error " Unable to extend an ID table - insufficient memory" (especially when trying  File --> Replication --> Settings, and entering 0 (zero) days in the "Remove documents not modified in the last" which has always be my good friend)?

Comment: Could you File copy **without** document and then make a simple action agent that copy all docs to the new DB? You will have to replicate this new DB on all your servers. Probably proceed 2 steps to copy the docs.

Comment: @Emmanuel  Thanks for your replies.  To answer your first question, tried the zero days.  There's actually a POST on web, forget url right now, that says also try setting to 1 then 0.  I've tried setting future dates on the "Other" tabs to 2 days into future etc.  From Richard's post below, I may have run into some limitation...but to answer your second question, that's exactly what I did.  I created a new blank copy, and ran an agent to copy across the docs, took 30mins for 600,000, so not bad.  Next step will mean I can reuce to 300,000.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the code in Domino that actually purges deletion stubs cannot work when the total number of modified docs + stubs is too high.  I think it's probably a limitation that's pretty deep in the Notes API internals, combined with the algorithm that has to be used -- which is to look at all notes modified before the purge interval date -- a potentially very large number.

Your best option may be  to make a local non-replica copy and re-deploy.

I researched this a while back.  I found some LotusScript code that uses Notes C API calls to purge deletion stubs posted on various blogs.  (I think the original code may have come from Rod Whitely, but I'm not sure.)  My version code is below.

When run on a database where the total of docs + stubs is somewhere between 2 and 3 million, it gets the "Unable to extend an ID table - insufficient memory".  I never did contact IBM support about this, as it was really just a side project for me.  I ended up just making non-replica copies of the production databases and then setting the purge interval low enough so that the number of stubs never got too high again.

```
Declare Private Sub IDDestroyTable Lib wAPIModule Alias "IDDestroyTable" _
( ByVal hT As Long)
Declare Private Function IDScan Lib wAPIModule Alias "IDScan" _
( ByVal hT As Long, ByVal F As Integer, ID As Long) As Integer
Declare Private Function NSFDbOpen Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbOpen" _
( ByVal P As String, hDB As Long) As Integer
Declare Private Function NSFDbClose Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbClose" _
( ByVal hDB As Long) As Integer
Declare Private Function NSFDbGetModifiedNoteTable Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFDbGetModifiedNoteTable" _
( ByVal hDB As Long, ByVal C As Integer, ByVal S As Currency, U As Currency, hT As Long) As Integer
Declare Private Function NSFNoteDelete Lib wAPIModule Alias "NSFNoteDelete" _
( ByVal hDB As Long, ByVal N As Long, ByVal F As Integer) As Integer
Declare Private Function OSPathNetConstruct Lib wAPIModule Alias "OSPathNetConstruct" _
( ByVal NullPort As Long, ByVal Server As String, ByVal FIle As String, ByVal PathNet As String) As Integer
Declare Private Sub TimeConstant Lib wAPIModule Alias "TimeConstant" _
( ByVal C As Integer, T As Currency)

Function countAndDeleteStubsByOpenDatabase(db As NotesDatabase, deleteFlag As boolean) As Long

        If db Is Nothing GoTo bail

        Dim forever As Currency
        Dim last As Currency
        Dim hT As Long
        Dim RRV As Long
        Dim hDB As Long
        Dim path As String
        Dim nStubs As Long
        Dim ret As integer

        On Error GoTo bail  

        path = Space(1024)
        Call OSPathNetConstruct(0, db.Server, db.FilePath, path)
        Call NSFDbOpen(path, hDB)

        Call TimeConstant(2, forever)
        Call NSFDbGetModifiedNoteTable(hDB, &H7FFF, forever, last, hT)

        nStubs = 0

        ret = IDScan(hT, True, RRV)

        While Not (ret = 0)
            If RRV < 0 Then
                If (deleteFlag = true) Then 
                    NSFNoteDelete hDB, RRV And &H7FFFFFFF, &H0201 
                End If
                nStubs = nStubs + 1
            End If
            ret = IDScan(hT, False, RRV)
        Wend

        IDDestroyTable hT
        NSFDbClose hDB

        If deleteFlag = True Then
            Print "Deleted " + CStr(nStubs) + " stubs for " + db.Filepath  + " on " + db.Server
        Else
            Print "Counted " + CStr(nStubs) + " stubs for " + db.Filepath  + " on " + db.Server 
        End If


        countAndDeleteStubsByOpenDatabase = nStubs

        On Error GoTo 0

        Exit Function

        bail:
            Print "Unexpected error in countAndDeleteStubsByOpenDatabase. Line " + CStr(Erl) + " " + CStr(Err()) + " " + Error(Err())
            countAndDeleteStubsByOpenDatabase = 0

    End Function
```

I never tried it, but it also occurred to me that it might be possible to modify this code to just search for the most recent one day's worth of stubs, delete them, then go back one more day and get the most recent stubs, delete those, etc.  It might not be all that easy to do in LotusScript, though, given that you have to deal with the C TIMEDATE struc as a Currency field.  You might have to do it in C.  Of course, deleting the newest stubs first is the exact reverse of what you want to do in practice, but this strategy might work around the limitation on idtables.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your reply.

Comment: @nickwall If you resolve this, either by calling IBM Support (perhaps they have a tool...) or on your own, I would love to hear the outcome, especially if it doesn't involve making new non-replica copies.

Comment: @Richard...My post is too long...trimming it. I've followed your blogs\ writings for years with great interest, so firstly...hi there.  I have resolved the issue, but unfortunately not as a non-replica.   I was really constrained by time.  I tried the agent you posted above, but it would crash my dev 8.5.3 server on the NSFDbOpen line...will verify. I deleted docs, copied to another DB. If deleted and use purge interval, only seemed to remove 10,000ish stubs at a time, too long for 835,000 stubs. I did del' 600K docs other day and did CL COPY, did not check via SH DB, so maybe were stubs.

Comment: I'm moving another 300,000 docs out just after Xmas, will be a more "relaxed" process time wise.  I'll try the agent again, and will post results here.

Comment: I haven't blogged in so long!  I'm glad you remember me. Thanks!  Re crashing the server... Hmmm... I always ran it on a client.  Is it by any chance a 64 bit server?  I don't think I've ever tried calling C API functions from LotusScript on Win64 + 64bit Domino, and it wouldn't surprise me if the declarations would have to be adjusted. That's just a guess, of course.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ytria.com/ has a tool ScanEZ that has a function to delete deletion stubs comfortably. I'm not sure if it would help if you're hitting against internal Notes limits as Richard suggested, but it might be worth a try.