# Programmatically purge document deletion

Tags: lotus-domino

I've a database with an agent that periodically delete (via Java agent, "removePermanently" method) all documents in a view and re-create them.

After some month, i've noticed that database size is considerably increased.
Showing database information through this command

```
sh database <dbpath>
```

it results that i've a lot of deleted documents (i suppose they are deletion stubs)

```
Document Type                        Live         Deleted
Documents                            1,922        817,378
```

Compacting database, 80% space was recovered.

Is there a way to programmatically delete stubs definitively to avoid "database explosion"? Or, is there a way to correctly manage this scenario (deletion and creation of documents)?

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete the documents!  Re-use them.  That's the best answer.  Seriously. Take the existing documents, clear the fields and set Form := "Obsolete".  Modify the selection formula for all your views by appending `& Form != "Obsolete"` Create a new hidden view called "Obsolete" with selection formula `Form = "Obsolete"`, and instead of creating new documents, change your code to go to the Obsolete view, grab an available document and set new field values (including changing the Form field). Only create new documents if there are not enough available in the Obsolete view. Any performance that you lose by doing this, which really should be minimal with the number of documents that you seem to have, will be more than offset by what you will gain by avoiding the growth and fragmentation of the NSF file that you are creating by doing all the deletions and creating new documents.

If, however, there's no possible way for you to do that -- maybe some third party tool that is outside of your control is creating the documents -- then it's important to know if the database you are talking about is replicated.   If it is replicated, then you must be very careful because purging deletion stubs before all replicas are brought up to date will cause deleted documents to "come back to life" if a replica that has been off-line since before the delete occurs comes back on-line.

If the database is not replicated at all, or is reliably replicated across all replicas quickly, then you can reduce the purge interval. Go to the Replication Settings dialog, find the checkbox labeled "Remove documents not modified in the last __ days".  Do **not** check the box, but enter a small number into the number of days.  The purge interval for deletion stubs will be set to 1/3 of this number. So if you set it to 3 the effect will be that stubs are kept for 1 day and then purged, giving you 24 hours to assure that all replicas are up to date.  If you need more, set the interval higher, maintaining the 3x multiple as needed.  If a server is down for an extended period of time (longer than your purge interval), then adjust your operations procedures so that you will be **sure** to disable replication of the database to that server before it comes back on line and the replica can be deleted and recreated. Be aware, though, that user replicas pose the same problem, and it's not really possible to control or be aware of user replicas that might go off-line for longer than the purge interval. In any case, remember: do **not** check the box. To reduce the purge interval for deletion stubs *only*, just reduce the number.

Apart from this, the only way to programmatically delete deletion stubs requires use of the Notes C API.  It's possible to call the required routines from LotusScript, but in my experience once the total number of stubs plus documents gets too high you will likely run into an error and may have to create and deploy a new non-replica copy of the database to get past it.  You can find code along with my explanation in the answer to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802135/unable-get-600-000-deletion-stubs-ro-purge-from-database).

Answer (score 2):

I have to second Richard's recommendation to reuse documents. I recently had a similar project, and started the way you did with deleting everything and importing half a million records every night. Deletion stubs and the growth of the FT index quickly became problems, eating up huge amounts of disk space and slowing performance significantly. I tried to manage the deletion stubs, but I was clearly going against the grain of Domino's architecture.

I read Richard's suggestion here, and adopted that approach. Here's what I did:

1) create 2 views based on form - one for 'active' records, and another for 'inactive' records

2) start the agent by setting autoupdate = false for both views

3) use stampall("form", "inactive") to change all fo the active records to inactive

4) manually refresh the 2 views using notesview.refresh()

5) start importing data. for each record, pull a document out of the pool of inactive records (by walking the 'inactive' view)

6) if if run out of inactive records in the pool, create new ones

7) when import is complete, manually refresh the views again

8) use db.createftindex(0, true) to re-create the FT index

the code is really not that complex, and it runs in about the same amount of time, if not faster, than my original approach.

Thanks Richard!

Also, look at the advanced db properties - several things there that will help optimize the db.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are "refreshing" the contents of the database by periodically deleting all the documents and creating new ones from some other source. Cut that out. If the data are in the Notes database already, leave the document alone. What you're doing is very inefficient.

Comment: My goal is to import from an external registry all entries about people, so i dont' know its changes (update, deletions, new insertions and so on) to keep it aligned. The best way for me is to delete all documents and recreate again..